# Sentencia SQL no me toma la id en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente problema con `PHP`, primero que nada envío los datos de una fila seleccionada desde una tabla a un modal, el cual me muestra los datos en un formulario, esto lo hago para que se puedan modificar los datos y para esto también le envío la `id` a un `input` existente dentro del modal, para que luego envíe esa `Id` a una variable `PHP`

El problema es que tanto `Ajax` como `PHP` me guardan todos los datos en las variables, las que quiero modificar, pero al momento de usar la sentencia `UPDATE` no me toma la variable `ID` y no me modifica los datos en la tabla

Codigo `PHP`:

```
<?php 
include "conexion.php";



$id=(isset($_POST['id']))?$_POST['id']:"";

$rut=(isset($_POST['rut']))?$_POST['rut']:"";
$nombre=(isset($_POST['nombre']))?$_POST['nombre']:"";
$telefono=(isset($_POST['telefono']))?$_POST['telefono']:"";
$direccion=(isset($_POST['direccion']))?$_POST['direccion']:"";
$comuna=(isset($_POST['comuna']))?$_POST['comuna']:"";

$sexo=(isset($_POST['sexo']))?$_POST['sexo']:"";

$tipo=(isset($_POST['tipo_licencia']))?$_POST['tipo_licencia']:"";




                    $sql = "UPDATE archivo_pdf SET rut='$rut',

                                                    nombre='$nombre',

                                                    telefono='$telefono',

                                                    direccion='$direccion',

                                                    comuna='$comuna',

                                                    sexo='$sexo',

                                                    tipo_licencia='$tipo'

                                    where id_archivo='$id' ";


echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) ;
```

?>

Como ya les dije, la `id` si se guarda en la variable porque eso ya lo comprobé, el problema es que no me la toma como identificador en la sentencia entonces no genera los cambios a la fila correspondiente del `id`, Aunque aun así me dice que se ha ejecutado correctamente, alguien sabe a que se deba?

PD: mando la `id` a este `input`, no se si tenga que ver con que sea tipo numérico y o string y que por eso no me la toma:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="eid">
```

Espero alguien sepa responder a mi duda o por lo menos sacar conclusiones juntos, porque la verdad no entiendo el porque no toma la `ID`

Comment: De que tipo es la columna `id_archivo`?

Comment: es de tipo numerico auto incrementable primary key

Answer (score 1):

Intenta dejar el }`sql` así

```
     $sql = "UPDATE archivo_pdf SET rut='$rut',

                                                nombre='$nombre',

                                                telefono='$telefono',

                                                direccion='$direccion',

                                                comuna='$comuna',

                                                sexo='$sexo',

                                                tipo_licencia='$tipo'

                                where id_archivo= $id ";
```

Sí el `id_archivo` es de tipo numérico no tiene porque llevar comillas en el `where`. espero que te sirva, saludos

Answer (score 0):

no le estas pasando ningún valor

```
   value=""
```

tendría que ser asi,

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="tuvariable" id="eid">
```

si es php tienes que poner `<?=$tuvariable?>`